# ActiveRecord Query for Present belongs_to ID but belongs_to Object is Nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I wasn't really sure how to title this because everything I have searched for just gives me some form of the following query: `Telephone.where(user_id: nil)` which is **not** what I'm looking for

I have two models:

```
Class Telephone < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :user, optional: true
end

Class User < ApplicationRecord
 has_one :telephone, dependent: :nullify
end
```

There was a bug in the code that wasn't always nullifying the `user_id` on a `telephone` when a `user` object was destroyed.  I need to do a data clean up and set the `user_id` to `nil` for all affected `telephones`.  I wrote the following bit of code to update the ~80 `telephones`, but there are >400000 records that get returned in the initial query so it takes a long time to loop through:

```
telephones = Telephone.where.not(user_id: nil)

telephones.each do |telephone|
  return unless telephone.user.nil?

  telephone.user_id = nil
  telephone.save
end
```

What is an Active Record query I could write to return all `telephones` with a present `user_id` but the `user` object is nil?

Comment: Once you clean things up you should add a foreign key constraint inside the database to keep this from happening again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following should get you telephones with `user_id` present but corresponding `user` object is `nil`.

```
Telephone.left_outer_joins(:user).where("users.id is NULL AND telephones.user_id is NOT NULL")
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `left_joins` on `user` association:

```rb
Telephone.left_joins(:user).where.not(user: nil).where("users.id": nil)
```

what is converted to a SQL-query

```sql
SELECT "telephones".* FROM "telephones" LEFT OUTER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "telephones"."user_id" WHERE "telephones"."user_id" IS NOT NULL AND "users"."id" IS NULL
```